Use conda virtual env without modifying or using any users home directory
I'm curently building an rpm package with a python 3.10 application including a anaconda virtual env.
The app can (and must) be called by any user without the need to modify their .bashrc file or anything else in their home dir
Till using conda from a python 3.10 dist it was possible to enable the venv using the old way by sourcing an
/path/to/python_venv/bin/activate file using a wrapper script which then called the python binary with the application script as parameter.
Newer Versions of conda environments (from anaconda distribution) require this weird conda init stuff in .bashrc which does some magic things I don't understand.
Of course I could do a conda init on a reference machine and move the generated stuff to my wrapper script but I'd like to know if there's a minimal command set to place here, since this is called every time my app get's called.
What can I put in my wrapper script to activate the venv, instaed of the old source command
without doing magic things like changing promt and whatever this conda init stuff does elsewhere ?

IMO, Conda isn't the right solution for this (especially not Anaconda). Rather, seems more appropriate for containerization (e.g., Docker). Maybe have a look at micromamba-docker.

Maybe but I don‘t build a container, I‘m building an rpm package. And this worked fine since years.

You can inspect what Conda does with activation using conda shell.posix activate foo (where foo is the environment name). You probably want to do that with no other environments activated, otherwise it will include deactivation steps for the current environment. Mainly just two things: 1) put the environment's bin/ directory on PATH and 2) source any package-specific activation scripts found in the environment's etc/conda/activate.d/ directory.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

well using conda without a path assumes to already have a basic environment. I my case that‘s not what I have.
I need a solution to build an rpm package which extracts on installation an app with it’s own virtual env with no other prerequisites needed on the system. Especially no basic python installation. Therefore sourcing a script with it‘s full path was the way to go.
This seems not to work anymore in newer anaconca python distributions. I will try to checkout your recommended command just to understand what magic happens and get back when I’ve learned more.
Thnks for your hint so far.
